# How to detect that web site visitor is not using any browser

Tags: asp.net, browser, web-crawler, bots

last time i was in situation where i need to detect bot and i solved this way.

```
public class Utility
{
    public static bool IsCrawlByBot()
    {
        List<string> Crawlers = new List<string>()
        {
            "googlebot","bingbot","yandexbot","ahrefsbot","msnbot","linkedinbot","exabot","compspybot",
            "yesupbot","paperlibot","tweetmemebot","semrushbot","gigabot","voilabot","adsbot-google",
            "botlink","alkalinebot","araybot","undrip bot","borg-bot","boxseabot","yodaobot","admedia bot",
            "ezooms.bot","confuzzledbot","coolbot","internet cruiser robot","yolinkbot","diibot","musobot",
            "dragonbot","elfinbot","wikiobot","twitterbot","contextad bot","hambot","iajabot","news bot",
            "irobot","socialradarbot","ko_yappo_robot","skimbot","psbot","rixbot","seznambot","careerbot",
            "simbot","solbot","mail.ru_bot","spiderbot","blekkobot","bitlybot","techbot","void-bot",
            "vwbot_k","diffbot","friendfeedbot","archive.org_bot","woriobot","crystalsemanticsbot","wepbot",
            "spbot","tweetedtimes bot","mj12bot","who.is bot","psbot","robot","jbot","bbot","bot"
        };

        string ua = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower();
        bool iscrawler = Crawlers.Exists(x => ua.Contains(x));
        return iscrawler;
    }
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (!Request.Browser.Crawler)
    if (!Utility.IsCrawlByBot())
    {
        string strCountryCookie = BBAreman.CountryCookie.GetCookieValue();
        string strShippingCookie = BBAreman.CountryCookie.GetShippingCookieValue();
        if (Request.Url.ToString().IndexOf(".asmx") == -1)
        {
            if (strCountryCookie.Trim() == "" || strShippingCookie.Trim() == "")
            {
                if (Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority).ToString() + "/index.aspx?ShowCountry=true" != HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString())
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx?ShowCountry=true");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

now i am in situation where i need to know my web site is accessing by a application other than any browser. i could develop a routine which will return many browser name but the problem is i know only few browser majorly used from pc. how to get all popular or not popular browser user agent name may be used from pc, any device or mobile. if i get it then my job will be easier to log report only when my web site would be accessed by application other than browser.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: Have you looked at Browscap? http://browscap.org/

Comment: @Tim what is browserCap....please tell me bit about it. i just go to the link but could not assume what it is and how i can use it to solve my issue.

Comment: It's a file that lists the major browsers, bots and what they support. If you want a popular browser/bot, it's probably listed in there. There's probably a listing for unknown - I don't know for sure, you'll need to look - but if there is, that's probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if html/text is supported.

```
if(Request.Browser.PreferredRenderingMime == "text/html")
{
    Response.Write("This is an HTML device.");
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.preferredrenderingmime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That has nothing to do with the actual browser. That has only to do with what the user agent is pretending to be.

Answer (score 1):

First google link. But it requires java.

http://uadetector.sourceforge.net

Comment: it looks good but i need solution based on .Net technology. anything exist similar for dotnet? tell me what are the keyword i should use for google search